# Ignore multiple outputs when number of output params in tuple is unknown

Tags: python, tuples

I have a function which returns a tuple of either 2, or 3 values (depending upon the size of matrix). I need only the first two, and discard the 3rd value, in case it's there.
**Is there a single line solution for this?**

Kindly note (before marking this question as a duplicate), these solutions do not work:

(1)

```
(x,y, _) = myfunc() # Won't work since myfunc() may return only two values
```

(2)

```
out = myfunc()     # This solution is not one-line
x = out[0]
y = out[1]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can slice the output of the function to retrieve only the first two items:

```
x, y = myfunc()[:2]
```

Or use *extended unpacking* in Python 3 which will also handle *generator functions* and functions returning *iterators* or *generator expressions* for which the previous slice notation cannot be applied directly:

```
x, y, *_ = myfunc()
```

Answer (score 4):

this should do the trick

```
x, y = myfunc()[:2]
```

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3 you can use the *catch-all* prefix `*`

```
a, b, *rest = myfunc()
```

(or use the disposable placeholder variable `_` in place of `rest` if you don't need the rest)